# A masked array indexing issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array with some `NaN` values:

```
arr = [ 0, NaN, 2, NaN, NaN, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

Using some logic (outside of the question scope), I generate a mask of the NaN locations:

```
mask = [ True, False, True, False, False, True, True, True ]
```

I use this mask to select only the valid data:

```
valid_arr = arr[mask]   # [ 0, 2, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

I then perform an arbitrary algorithm which selects several `indeces` in this new array:

```
indeces = myAlgo(valid_arr)   # [ 1, 3 ]
```

The `indeces` in the valid array are 1,3 (corresponding to values 2 and 6).  I need to know what `indeces` these correspond to *in the original array* (`arr`).  In the above example, this is obviously **2 and 6**.

The array is time series data, not sorted.  One solution is to iterate over the `mask`, incrementing a counter only when valid numbers are found.  Can this be done more efficiently using numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flat the mask which returns indices from the original array, and then use the new indices to subset the mask indices:

```
mask = np.array([ True, False, True, False, False, True, True, True ])
indices = [1,3]

np.flatnonzero(mask)[indices]
# array([2, 6])
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about how this works.  Based on the numpy docs, `flatnonzero(a) returns indices that are non-zero in the flattened version of a`.  I take it this also works with the True/False mask array?

Comment: It does. `True` is treated as 1 and `False` is treated as 0 here, as are under most cases when implicit type conversion happens.

Comment: Ahh, I understand.. and it contains the indeces corresponding to the original array! Outstanding!

Answer (score 2):

You could create an index array (using [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)) then mask that and finally use [advanced indexing using an integer array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to get the corresponding items:

```
>>> mask = np.array([ True, False, True, False, False, True, True, True ])
>>> np.arange(mask.size)[mask][[1, 3]]
array([2, 6])
```